# Use single IEnumerable value before For Each

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I have a view that lists auditorium names of a theater.

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of dbtheatersinfo.TheaterAuditorium)
<h2>Theater Auditoriums</h2>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Theater.TheaterName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.TheaterAuditoriumName)
        </th>
    </tr>

@For Each item In Model
    @<tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Theater.TheaterName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.TheaterAuditoriumName)
        </td>
    </tr>
Next
</table>
```

All auditoriums listed here have the same TheaterName, so I would like to display the first instance of TheaterName in the  tag (and remove it from the list).  I tried:

```
<h2>Auditoriums for @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.Theater.TheaterName) </h2>
```

But that gives me, "'Theater' is not a member of 'IEnumerable(of TheaterAuditorium)'."  The data is in there; it's displaying within the For Each loop.  I just can't figure out how to use it before the loop.

Comment: You can always just get the first item in the collection - `@Model.First().Theater.TheaterName`

Comment: You can use `First` as suggested as long as there will definitely be at least one item in the list.  If there may be no items then you'd need to use `FirstOrDefault` and account for the fact that it might be `Nothing`. You can use null propagation for that in VB 2015 or later, e.g. `model.FirstOrDefault?.Theater.TheaterName`.  Either way, you should then use `Model.Skip(1)` in your loop so that the first item is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the wrong question, but ended up needing the answer anyway.  To do this View properly, I needed a View Model:

```
Namespace ViewModels
    Public Class AuditoriumIndex
        Public Property TheaterAuditorium As IEnumerable(Of TheaterAuditorium)
        Public Property Theater As Theater
    End Class
End Namespace
```

In the controller:

```
Dim viewModel = New AuditoriumIndex()
viewModel.TheaterAuditorium = db.TheaterAuditoriums.Where(Function(a) a.TheaterID = id).SortBy("TheaterAuditoriumName")
viewModel.Theater = db.Theaters.Where(Function(a) a.TheaterID = id).SingleOrDefault()
Return View(viewModel)
```

And the View:

```
h2>Auditoriums for @Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.Theater.TheaterName)</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.TheaterAuditorium.FirstOrDefault().TheaterAuditoriumName)
        </th>
    </tr>

@For Each item In Model.TheaterAuditorium
    @<tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.TheaterAuditoriumName)
        </td>
    </tr>
Next
</table>
```

Here I had to use FirstOrDefault() to access the column name outside of the loop.